# Global vector descriptor

Tags: opencv, image-processing, locality-sensitive-hash

Usually, algorithms as [SIFT](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/da/df5/tutorial_py_sift_intro.html), [SURF](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_surf_intro/py_surf_intro.html) and many others provdies a set of `k` keypoints and the associated descriptor in `d` dimension (for example, in SIFT each descriptor has `d=128` dimensions).

So, in order to **describe an image** we need a matrix `kxd` (`k` descriptor vectors, each one in `d` dimensions). So far so good.

**My question is: how can we describe an image through a single vector?**

This could be really useful since we could save a lot of space and because certain algorithms (like [LSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing)) requires a vector as input/query.

In some papers (for example [this](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~grauman/papers/iccv2009_klsh.pdf), section 6.5) this approach is described as "global descriptors".

Up to know, I found only [this paper](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/3383-spectral-hashing.pdf) but it doesn't seem so accurate (and it's from 2009, not so new).

**UPDATE:**
Other possible solutions (some suggested in the comments):

- Visual bag of words
- [gist](http://cvcl.mit.edu/papers/IJCV01-Oliva-Torralba.pdf) descriptor

Comment: This does seem to be a programming question as such, it may be more appropriate for http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-processing

Comment: Simplest thing is Bag of Words (BoW), where you basically aggregate local descriptors into a single fixed size vector.

Comment: @Miki Can you tell me more about them?

Comment: Google for that. Too broad to explain here.. It's a well known (and simple) approach, you'll find it easily. It's called also _bag of visual words_

Comment: As I wrote on the **update** section, the gist descriptor is another solution